# eCommerce and Product Categories Manage Two Separate ORM Models

Tags: orm, odoo, odoo-website, odoo-product-category, odoo-orm

I understood the both have two different purposes and usage but I want to know bit more on some technical side.

What if we go with technical models where we can see Odoo managing the two different models for the Product Categories.

**e-commerce categories --> product.public.category model**

**Internal product categories --> product.category model**

Why we can not follow the single category and managing everything with boolean flag/other relation fields over the one common model.
Here why we are managing two separate models for the same.

Do we have any technical challenges with single model ?

I am following the post [odoo-forum-post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/why-ecommerce-and-product-categories-are-separe-185129)